# Use a variable derived from Javascript into an ASP tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm having difficulty in using a variable derived from Javascript into an ASP tag .

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    if (arg) 
    {
        var text_box_to_fill = arg.sendValue_Code;                  
        document.getElementById( document.getElementById("<%= "+text_box_to_fill+".clientID %>").value = selected_libelle_value;
    }
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can only render something on the server into the client, but can't go in the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why there are duplicate "document.getElementById" code references, but you can only go from server to client in this fashion.  So it would be:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    if (arg) 
    {
        var text_box_to_fill = arg.sendValue_Code;                  
        document.getElementById("<%= text_box_to_fill.ClientID %>").value = selected_libelle_value;
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Note that you have to have the script in the same page or control as the origin of "text_box_to_fill".  If you have this script in a page, and the textbox is in the user control, that won't work.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'text_box_to_fill' is not declared.

Comment: this is the message my compiler is sending back to me

Comment: You have to use the server-side control's ID.  What is the ID of the textbox?  Also edited response above.

Comment: I finally found a way. This is the ID of the textbox that I have in "var text_box_to_fill" so I use it directly in javascript like this :document.getElementById(text_box_to_fill).value = selected_libelle_value; and it Works. thank for your help

Comment: I was obsessed by using server tag ! now it's Ok. Smile.

Answer (score 0):

`text_box_to_fill` is defined client side in the browser, whereas the <% %> tags are evaluated on the server. It's not possible to reference javascript variables from the server code.

Comment: I've noticed that @andy Magee ! but are not there any others ways to fix it ?